# How to calculate percent of width programmatically Android?

Tags: java, android, algorithm, kotlin

For example I got a screen width 1000 . And I need to calculate the value of the first 25% which will be `when x in 0..250 -> doSmth()` and last part

which will be `when x in 750..1000 -> doSmth()`

But I need to make it dynamically depends on the screen width. What is the way to do that in Android?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/how-to-get-screen-dimensions-as-pixels-in-android

Comment: @Tenfour04 I don't need to get just dimensions. I know how to get them. I need help to get % of the screen dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the width, let's say `w` is the width value, it's 25% is

```
w / 100 * 25
```

I don't know if this is your question.

Comment: but how can I get the values from 75% to 100%?

Comment: The range from 75% to 100% is from w/100*75 to w

Answer (score 0):

Divide by the width using float values to avoid integer division truncating the result to 0. Then compare to fractions of 1 instead of integer percentages.

```
when (x.toFloat() / screenWidth) { 
    in 0f..0.25f -> doSmth()
    in 0.75f..1f -> doSmthElse()
}
```

Comment: Coming in Kotlin 1.7, the last branch of a `when` with subject will have to be an `else` branch, so you'd replace that last condition with `else`.